# Compare directory using winmerge?

Tags: diff, winmerge

I have two different directories and i am making a script which identify that if different directories have the same file name with different changes.i am trying with winmerge commaline option as below ..
WinMergeU C:\Folder\File.txt  C:\Folder2

and i also want to merge the all changes into the one file.

Please suggest me on this.

thanks

Comment: So you want to find out the differences between the common files in two directories and merge those changes into one of the files. Is that correct?

Comment: yes i want that only,could you please help me on this

Comment: Checking the "include subfolders" option when selecting folders to compare is the real answer to this question.

Answer (score 14):

When I compare folders with WinMerge, I go to File->Open, select folders and check the 'Include subfolders' check-box. Then in the View menu I switch on the Tree View and switch off Show Identical Items.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the manual from Winmerge explaining on comparing two different folders -

http://winmerge.org/docs/manual/CompareDirs.html

Comment: I have to dig through each (sub, sub-) folder to see if there are identical or different files in there...   also after looking at the manual. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the box "Include Subfolders" in the dialog in which you select the folders to compare, and you will get a flat view (i.e. not a directory structure) of all files in the target folders and all their subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Stanislav works well from the user interface.

From the command line ([documentation](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html)), you need the flag `/r` to do the comparison recursively:

```
WinMergeU /r Folder1 Folder2
```

Then, as mentioned in Stanislav's post, you can go to the View Menu and Check the "Tree Mode" and uncheck "Show Identical Items" to get a clearer view of the differences.